# Printing php script output to file

Tags: php

Is there a native function or set of functions in PHP that will allow me to `echo` and print php file output into file.

For example code will generate HTML DOM that needs to be put into .html file and then displayed as static page.

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: the simplest way i can think of is using [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Appreciate your help but I think that the question was misunderstood. By "php file output" I meant not simple variable or string but an output of script that is made of varius classes, objects, required files etc. and, as an end result, creates complete HTML DOM (with tags, content etc.) that I want to print to file instead of passing it directly to browser.

Comment: @coo - I think you'll find what you are looking for in my recent edit.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The easiest method would be to create a string of your HTML data and use the [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function.

```
$htmlStr = '<div>Foobar</div>';
file_put_contents($fileName, $htmlStr);
```

To create this string, you'll want to *capture* all outputted data. For that you'll need to use the `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean` output control functions:

```
// Turn on output buffering
ob_start();
echo "<div>";
echo "Foobar";
echo "</div>";

//  Return the contents of the output buffer
$htmlStr = ob_get_contents();
// Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
ob_end_clean(); 
// Write final string to file
file_put_contents($fileName, $htmlStr);
```

---

Reference -

- [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)
- [`ob_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php)
- [`ob_end_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)
- [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)
- [PHP output control documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

Comment: Think that's the one. Will give it a try. Thx

Comment: Thanks, man!!! spent a lot of time today trying to convert web script that makes XLS files to the one that works in command line. That's the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

```
file_put_contents($filename, $data)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP provides a few functions that allows you to right to a file, you choose:

1. [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php);
2. [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).