# Mandrill inbound emails through Laravel / PHP

Tags: php, laravel, mandrill

I was wondering if someone could help me with a problem I have been having some trouble researching related to Laravel and inbound email processing through Mandrill. 
Basically I wish to be able to receive emails through Mandrill and store them within my Laravel database. Now i'm not sure if i'm reading through the documentation with the wrong kind of eyes, but Mandrill says it deals with inbound email as well as outbound, however i'm starting to think that Mandrill deals with inbound email details as opposed to the actual inbound email, such as if the message is sent etc.

I've created a new Mandrill account, created an API key, created an inbound domain and corresponding subdomain of my site (e.g. inboundmail.myproject.co.uk), set the MX record and the MX record is showing as valid. From there i have set up a route (e.g. queries@inboundmail.myproject.co.uk), and a corresponding webhook (myproject.co.uk/inboundmail.php) and within this webhook tried a variety of the examples given in the API (https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/inbound.php.html), such as adding a new route, checking the route and attempting to add a new domain. All of them worked and produced the correct results, so my authentication with Mandrill is not in question, but my real question is is there a specific webhook for dealing with accepting incoming mail messages?

I cant help but feel like an absolute idiot asking this question as i'm sure the answer is either staring me in the face or just not possible through Mandrill.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But Mandrill does accept incoming messages. What sort of webhook are you looking for?

Comment: basically an example of how to get the incoming mail. I want to get the data from the incoming email, so say an array of all the data for each email, parse it and then store it into a database. is this possible?
For instance if i sent an email from my email address to queries@inboundmail.myproject.co.uk, how would i then access that email from the webhook?

Comment: You should ask this on the Laravel forum.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to duellsy and debest for their help, in the end i found a script and expanded on it to add the mail to my own database and style / display it accordingly. Hope this helps someone who may have the same trouble:

```
<?php

require 'mandrill.php';

define('API_KEY', 'Your API Key');
define('TO_EMAIL', 'user@example.com');
define('TO_NAME', 'Foo Bar');

if(!isset($_POST['mandrill_events'])) {
    echo 'A mandrill error occurred: Invalid mandrill_events';
    exit;
}
$mail = array_pop(json_decode($_POST['mandrill_events']));

$attachments = array();
foreach ($mail->msg->attachments as $attachment) {
    $attachments[] = array(
        'type' => $attachment->type,
        'name' => $attachment->name,
        'content' => $attachment->content,
    );
}

$headers = array();
// Support only Reply-to header
if(isset($mail->msg->headers->{'Reply-to'})) {
    $headers[] = array('Reply-to' => $mail->msg->headers->{'Reply-to'});
}

try {
    $mandrill = new Mandrill(API_KEY);
    $message = array(
        'html' => $mail->msg->html,
        'text' => $mail->msg->text,
        'subject' => $mail->msg->subject,
        'from_email' => $mail->msg->from_email,
        'from_name' => $mail->msg->from_name,
        'to' => array(
            array(
                'email' => TO_EMAIL,
                'name' => TO_NAME,
            )
        ),
        'attachments' => $attachments,
        'headers' => $headers,
    );
    $async = false;
    $result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async);
    print_r($result);
} catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
    // Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
    echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
    // A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_PaymentRequired - This feature is only available for accounts with a positive balance.
    throw $e;
}
?>
```

Comment: This whole time I didn't realize you needed to `json_decode` the mandrill_events. I should've read the docs a bit closer, but +1 either way.

Comment: How can I debug the inbound mail easy? I would like to save for example the message text into a log file using `file_put_contents()`?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225437/printing-php-script-output-to-file

I'd just var_dump $message in to it.

Comment: I use this code at the moment to create "support tickets" in case there's a user account associated with the email. Is there a way to sent the whole email (with attachments) in case there's no user account associated to another mailbox from which I can answer? So just a simple "forward" of the whole mail.

Comment: I'm not sure, as it's already come from Mandrill you'd probably have to incorporate PHPs mail function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) into the solution, which would put it outside the context of this particular SO question

Comment: Seriously late to this party, but it should be noted that Mandrill only processes the route POST once per minute. If more than one email comes in they will all be included in the mandrill_events array... the code sample here is throwing away all but the last email, if there are multiples. https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/guides/set-up-inbound-email-processing/#handle-parsed-emails

Answer (score 1):

Like using webhooks from other mail parsing services, you'll need to make use of

```
file_get_contents("php://input")
```

This will give you the raw data from the webhook, which you can then `json_decode` and work with the results.