# Laravel Email Reply to Forum

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This might be pretty far out there, but I thought I'd ask. I have developed a program in Laravel 4 where it is like forum where it emails the people. I was asked if there was a way to make it where the users can reply to the email and make it appear in the forum.

I know other sites have done that like Basecamp, but I didn't have to program it. Is there anyway to achieve this in Laravel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you'll need more than just Laravel. You can [pipe inbound emails to Laravel](http://www.sitepoint.com/piping-emails-laravel-application/) or you can use a third-party service like Mandrill's [inbound email handling](http://help.mandrill.com/forums/21092258-Inbound-Email-Basics) to accept and turn them into HTTP requests to your server.

Comment: That link actually made perfect sense. :) I'll have to try this out. Thanks!!!

Comment: Mandrill is pretty useful. Add a domain, set an email where users can reply to, and set an url where the event of a new email is sent. The event data is send through a post variable. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848563/mandrill-inbound-emails-through-laravel-php)

Comment: I tried setting up Mandrill once and failed, but it was a half hearted attempt. I'll look into it again. Thanks!