# Save xls file to directory and download in php

Tags: php, excel, postgresql, zip

I have a php code that selects an query from a postgres db and creates a xls file and downloads the same. The code is as follows :

```
    <?php

$xls_filename = 'filename.xls'; // Define Excel (.xls) file name

$Connect = pg_connect ("host=xxxx port=5432 dbname=xxxx user=xxx  password=xxx");

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM "tablename"';

$result = pg_query($sql);

header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$xls_filename");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

// Define separator (defines columns in excel &amp; tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; // tabbed character 

// Start of printing column names as names of fields
for ($i = 0; $i<pg_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    echo pg_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}

print("\n");
// End of printing column names

// Start while loop to get data
while($row = pg_fetch_row($result))
{
  $schema_insert = "";
  for($j=0; $j<pg_num_fields($result); $j++)
  {
    if(!isset($row[$j])) {
      $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
   }
    elseif ($row[$j] != "") {
      $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
    }
    else {
      $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
  }
  $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
  $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
  $schema_insert .= "\t";
  print(trim($schema_insert));
  print "\n";
  } 
  }

?>
```

I want to zip this xls file which is created rather then just downloading it.
How do I create a xls file in the directory instead of downloading it.

Comment: You can use `output_buffering` to do it. Take a look on [docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Comment: See a example in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16225500/7925366).

Comment: what is your file name?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your variable.when your file name has space you have to use quotes like below:

```
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$xls_filename'");
```

Comment: This is the remember to accept the answer if appropriate @Esteann Afonso

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code that work fine

```
            $fileNames = WWW_ROOT . 'uploads' . DS . 'export' . DS . 'DYNAMIC_FILE_NAME_'. $ANY_DYNAMIC_PART.'.xls';//Dynamic Path of the directory
            if (file_exists($fileNames)) {
                $file = $fileNames;
                header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
                header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                header("Content-Type: application/download");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"NEWFILENAME.xls\"");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                header("Pragma: no-cache");
                header("Expires: 0");
                readfile($fileNames);exit;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Downloading to excel is easy with the below approach. There are two ways to save the output, download using browser or download to a specific path.

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
ob_start(); // We'll be outputting an excel file 
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
// It will be called file.xlsx 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'.xlsx"'); 
----------------
//To download to a specific path
$objWriter->save('path/'.$filename.'.xlsx');
----------------
//Write file to browser
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```