# How to capture a HTTP session from the server without a shell

Tags: php, http, packet-capture

I am debugging a web app that communicates with a secure payment gateway provided by my client's bank. The secure gateway works the following way:

1. The end user's browser is redirected to the bank's website, where he has to input his credit card number.
2. If the authentication is successful, the **bank's server** (not the end user's browser) opens an HTTPS connection to an URL in our site, with the transaction data.
3. Our site needs to respond to that HTTPS connection with the string **"OK"**, and mark in our DB the transaction as paid. If our site doesn't respond, the gateway shows an error message to the end user, and the payment process is considered failed.
4. Then, the end user's browser is redirected from the bank's site to our own.

Anyway, the gateway has recently started showing intermittent errors. What's going on is:

- The orders get marked in our DB as paid.
- I check our server logs, and I see the connection from the bank's server, and I see an 200 response from our web server.
- ...and yet, the bank's gateway claims that the operation has failed because our server hasn't responded correctly.

So, what I'd like to do is to capture the HTTP dialogue between the bank's server and our own, to see what's going on exactly... but our site is hosted on a shared server (it's a standard LAMP stack). I obviously can't install anything on the bank's server to log the session from their end; is there any way to do so from our server's side?

(If it helps, our web app is written in PHP, so if there's some instruction that allows us to dump the raw HTTP dialog, that would be good too).

EDIT: to be clear, I don't need only the HTTP request that I'm receiving from the bank's server, but also the HTTP response that my app is sending back. I need to be able to verify independently that my app is indeed sending back the correct "OK" string, and there isn't some subtle bug that we missed.

Comment: mod_log_forensic *might* help.  Otherwise, setup a proxy or a sniffer to view the traffic on your server.  They will need the encryption keys you setup on your apache to decrypt the data, otherwise you will see only encrypted giberish.  For PHP, Try var_dump on the predefined variables, see if that is enough to understand (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php).

Comment: @Nic3500: thanks, but as I mentioned, our site is running on a shared server, where I can't really install any proxy... that I know of. If there is something that works "like a proxy", and can be run from inside a PHP web app, that would be perfect for me, but I don't know if such a beast exists...

Comment: Then try `For PHP, Try var_dump on the predefined variables, see if that is enough to understand (php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php).`.  This can be done in your PHP code.  Just output the var_dump into a log file.  Between the different predefined variables, you should get the vast majority of what you need.

Comment: 10 seconds in google: https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/650e30e485c0f91f2f40 and others (http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php), ...

Comment: @Nic3500: okay, perhaps I didn't explain myself correctly. I don't need to dump just the HTTP request that I receive, but also **the HTTP response that my app is sending back**. We haven't changed anything in our code, so it should be responding the "OK" string to the bank's server in all cases... but what if it isn't? What if there's some subtle bug that we missed? And if our code is correct and it's the bank's secure gateway the one messing up, it will also be helpful to get the full HTTP dialog in order to talk to their helpdesk.

Comment: Hey PaulJ in case capturing live bank traffic doesn't work out, and if editing PHP is faster, another approach is to make a  "debug" version of the bank response page, one that will allow you to use your browser to pretend to be the bank and open https://yourwebsite/testpage , where the testpage mimics the code used for responding to your bank, but without actually doing permanent damage such as writing to the transaction database. See if it actually returns "OK" as intended.

Comment: @PaulJ: sorry I did not get that you wanted the output as well.  Do you have shell access on the server?  Can you run `tcpdump` or similar commands?  For output you could use the strategy listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225437/printing-php-script-output-to-file